# which one is best practice to display lable in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display a label in View, which one is best practice?

```
@Html.Raw(Constants.lblProjectName)
```

or

```
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.ProjectName)
```

If yes please tell me the reason or

And my Property is

```
[Display(Name ="Project No.")]
public string ProjectName { get; set; } = ProjectNo.GetProjectNo;
```

Comment: Using `Html.Raw` can be quite dangerous, be careful with that. Anyway, this question is opinion based I'm afraid.

Comment: In general it probably makes more sense to use the HTML helpers like LabelFor. They exist to provide a superior experience compared to using the raw output (which can, as pointed out above, also expose you to security issues). Is there some particular reason you're curious about this?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons to prefer second approach:

1. It is much more flexible, because rather than showing the value directly, you use the model. So if in this particular place you want to show something else, all necessary code already exists.
2. You can make use of [display templates](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) to keep your custom styles consistent. Also count in the fact that if this value  becomes editable later on, you easily use editor templates too.
3. It is easier to read, because it is more standard MVC approach. Generally you want to follow standard approaches.
4. @GeorgPatscheider adds in comments: `@Html.LabelFor` will actually emit a `<label for="{InputId}">` tag, so a click on the label will focus the corresponding input field.
5. Finally, as @DavidG noticed in comments, `Html.Raw` is quite dangerous, because it does not do any html encoding for you.

Comment: Additional benefit: `@Html.LabelFor` will actually emit a `<label for="{InputId}">` tag, so a click on the label will focus the corresponding input field.